# Слетает кодировка, когда я пытаюсь считать Excel файл при помощи PHP

Tags: php, excel, кодировка

Всем привет, я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня есть файл parser.xls, когда я пытаюсь его считать при помощи PHP, слетает кодировка и на экране появляются т.н. "кракозябры". Вверху скрипта поставил проверку, что бы узнать поддерживается ли кодировка UTF-8, исключения не выбросило. `

```
const PAGE_ENCODING = 'UTF-8';
if (mb_internal_encoding(PAGE_ENCODING) != PAGE_ENCODING) {
    throw new Exception('Encoding not supported: ' . PAGE_ENCODING);
}

$filename = 'parser.xls';

$fileContent = file_get_contents($filename);

var_dump($fileContent);
```

`
Я знаю, что можно изменить разрешение excel файла на .csv, но есть ещё какой-либо способ считать этот файл именно в формате .xls. Т.к необходимо что бы файл, не подвергался каким-либо изменениям.

Comment: Возможно проблема в самом файле php, который нужно тоже иметь в нужной кодировке

Answer (score 0):

Вы не сможете правильно прочесть Excel файл с помощью функции [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php), поскольку она читает файл как текст, а не как электронную таблицу. Вам нужно воспользоваться какой-либо php - библиотекой для чтения файла Excel, например, [как написано здесь](https://r-band.ru/useful/how-to/chtenie-excel-na-php) или [здесь](https://snipp.ru/php/read-xls).